# How do I iterate through a dictionary and assign the value of each key to the matching property in another object?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to iterate over a dictionary and an entity.  Where the dict key matches the entity property I want to assign the key's value to be the value of the property.

My model code is:

```
class myModel(db.Model):
    Property1 = db.IntegerProperty()
    Property2 = db.StringProperty(required=True,choices=set(["this", "that", "other"]))
    Property3 = db.StringProperty()
```

My dict is:

```
{u'Property1': u'1234', u'Property2': u'trouble', u'Property3': u'2321'}
```

The code that I am using to iterate through both objects works, however it is skipping the validation in the model.  If I explicitly assign `myModel.Property2 = 'trouble'` I receive a BadValueError. However, in the code below I do not.

```
for le_attr, le_value in myModel.__dict__.iteritems():
    for key, value in Data[0].items():
        if ('_' + str(key)) == (str(le_attr)):
            myModel.__dict__[le_attr]= value
```

My thoughts are that no matter how many keys are in the dictionary, only the ones that match the properties will be assigned and all others ignored. With the code above, this works.

But is there a way to do this and still have the validation occur?

Comment: You should consider using Model.properties() call to actually get the list of properties that are defined in the model rather than assuming that anything in the your dict is in fact a real property in the model.  You could in theory have a name that matches something else in the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`dir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) and [`setattr()` functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) instead of poking into the `__dict__` structure:

```
for le_attr in dir(myModel)
    if le_attr in Data[0]:
        setattr(myModel, le_attr, Data[0][le_attr])
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked! I was noodling with setattr last night but couldn't quite get it.  This example cleared it up.